# Check if tool is equipped

Tags: lua, roblox

How do I determine in a condition if a tool is currently equipped?

The following is the LocalScript in my tool, called "Axe".

```
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Animation = script.Chop
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Character = Player.Character
UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, gameProcessedEvent)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
        local Character = Player.Character
        local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

        local A = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(Animation)
        A:Play()
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tools are parented under the character when equipped. Henceforth, you can just write the following condition:

`if Player.Character:FindFirstChild("Axe") ~= nil then`

Answer (score 0):

you can make a variable that can store a boolean and changes when the tool is equipped or unequipped

```
local isEquipped = false

Tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    isEquipped = true
end)

Tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    isEquipped = false
end)
```

Comment: Uhh is there a way to make it in "if then"

Comment: if Tool.Parent.Parent.Character:FindFirstChild(Tool.Name) then

Comment: Still does the animation even when its not equipped

Comment: Did you remove the mousebutton1?